# Woocomerce перевод на русский атрибуты товара

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть блок детали товара нужно перевести на русский,

в поле Весы значение **g** на **г.**

само поле нашел в woocommerce/templates/single-product/product_attributes.php

там нет **g** где найти это значение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не могу найти облазил весь woocommerce-ru_RU.po

только нашёл перевод в Вариативный товар поле Вес

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Искать надо в файле. po. Вы как переводите-то вообще?

Comment: Похоже, что это просто наименование атрибута новара. Откройте в админке Товары->Атрибуты /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&page=product_attributes и отредактируйте значения атрибута.

Comment: да нет там смотрел, прошёлся по woocommerce-ru_RU.po не там такого значения нашел перевод только в админке когда ставишь вариативный товар есть поле Вес вот только это перевёл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замени:

```
<?php echo esc_html( wc_format_weight( $product->get_weight() ) ); ?>
```

На:

```
<?php echo esc_html( $product->get_weight() ); ?> гр.
```